# how to get the difference between 2 dates in years and months in same query using sub queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, subquery, difference

I'm using the Northwind DB SQL and trying to get the difference between 2 dates in years with months on it not separate. Example employee hireDate 1992-05-01  should be 27 years 0 months and 1992-08-14  must be 2 years 8 months using today as the date to compare.
I want to get the results for each row of the table with other  values in one result example

FirstName| hireDate | hiredYears | hiredMonths
nancy     1992-05-01     6             11

This is my query

```
SELECT  months-(Age*12) FROM (

SELECT CASE WHEN dateadd(year, datediff (year, [HireDate], getdate()),[HireDate]) > getdate()
            THEN datediff(year, [HireDate], getdate()) - 1
            ELSE datediff(year, [HireDate], getdate())
       END as Age,

       (case when datepart(day,getdate()) >= datepart(day,[HireDate]) 
       then datediff(month, [HireDate], getdate())
       else datediff(month, [HireDate], dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))
       end) as months

FROM [Employees] 

) results;
```

The first query gave me the months and the subquery in years but I don't know how to create a subquery that shows everything together. Also, I will like to know if this subquery can have bad performance because I would like to use something similar in a table with a lot of records, any advice or link to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to divide the months by twelve to get the full years and use modulo twelve on them to get the remaining months. Use `concat()` to compose a string in the form of "n years m months".

```
SELECT concat(datediff(month, hiredate, getdate()) / 12,
              N' years ',
              datediff(month, hiredate, getdate()) % 12,
              N' months')
       FROM employees;
```

Comment: @UserEsp . . . I'm surprised you accepted this because it gives the wrong answer.  For someone who started in Dec 2018 it gives an answer of "1 years 5 months" in May 2019.  (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0026b950ca1caeea7a891cc5a089a40a).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Oops. You're right. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @GoronLinoff Thanks for the observations, You right get it in months and convert it is more accurate. I did not have the chance to test different scenarios.  The use of "%" it's really helpful to have all the data in one query.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right answer is to get the value in months and then do the arithmetic:

```
SELECT months / 12 as years,
       month % 12 as months
FROM employees e CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEDIFF(month, hiredate, getdate())
     ) v(months);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT FirstName, 
hireDate ,
DATEDIFF(YY,hireDate ,GETDATE()) hiredYears,
DATEDIFF(MM,hireDate ,GETDATE())%12 hiredMonths
FROM your_table
```